# HTTP Get in Android Studio API level 23+

Tags: java, android-studio, httprequest, android-studio-3.0

**Hi!**
I've been searching around on the Internet for how to make Http Get app in Android Studio, what I found was that you could add

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
```

to the dependencies for Android API level 23>. Or

```
android{          
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
 }
```

for Android API level 23+
And then I've been getting the Java code

```
HttpClient httpClient= HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request= new HttpGet(your_url_to_read);
request.setHeader("k1", "value1");
request.setHeader("k2", "value2");
HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(request);

System.out.println("Response Code : "+ response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
//want to read the response content?
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
String line = "";
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
```

by @user404. I've successfully been importing the other packages in the Java code below, but on line 1 Android Studio cannot import HttpClientBuilder. Then I came in on a thread about HttpClientBuilder in Android API level 23+ **(Which I forget where it was, but it was somewhere on StackOverflow)** there someone was saying that you can not import HttpClietBuilder in Android API 23+ because Google removed that feature.

So now I'm looking either for a method to import that HttpClientBuilder package **without downgrading the API level** or a whole new way to make an Http Get request in Java with headers, like 
"URL "http://www.something.com/random" HEADERS "Authorization": "123456ABCDEF""
, not parameters in the URL like "http://www.something.com/random?authorization=123456ABCDEF".

Thanks in forehand for answer

Answer (score 0):

It's just that the org.apache.http packages have been removed by default, so if you target API level 23, you'll need to do something extra to make these work.

Adding `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` to your Gradle is a way to fix this and you'll be able to target 23. However, you'll get the old implementation which is legacy for a reason.

Manually adding the latest version of Apache HttpClient as a dependency is a good choice and will continue to work regardless of which Android version you're targeting.

Likewise, you can use another HTTP library altogether like OkHttp. You can also use a library which is more higher level, like Retrofit.